# GlusterFS split brain with no path, what does it mean?

Tags: glusterfs

I was just checking the status of my glusterfs volumes and I have one with split-brain entries that have no path:

```
# gluster volume heal private_uploads info
Brick server01:/var/lib/glusterfs/brick01/uploads/
<gfid:4c0edafb-0c28-427c-a162-e530280b3396> - Is in split-brain
<gfid:42d62418-1be9-4f96-96c4-268230316869> - Is in split-brain
Number of entries: 2

Brick server02:/var/lib/glusterfs/brick01/uploads/
<gfid:42d62418-1be9-4f96-96c4-268230316869> - Is in split-brain
<gfid:4c0edafb-0c28-427c-a162-e530280b3396> - Is in split-brain
Number of entries: 2
```

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

I'm running GlusterFS 3.5.9:

```
# gluster --version
glusterfs 3.5.9 built on Mar 28 2016 07:10:17
Repository revision: git://git.gluster.com/glusterfs.git
```

Comment: Do you use only 2 server in your cluster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What is Split-Brain?

As mentioned in the [Official Documentation on Managing Split-Brain](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Storage/3/html/Administration_Guide/sect-Managing_Split-brain.html) provided by RedHat, **split-brain** is a state when a data or availability inconsistencies originating from the maintenance of two separate data sets with overlap in scope, either because of servers in a network design, or a failure condition based on servers not communicating and synchronizing their data to each other. And it is a term applicable to replicate configuration.

Pay attention that it is said *"a failure condition based on servers not communicating and synchronizing their data to each other"* - due to any likelihood - but it doesn't mean that your nodes might lose the connection. The Peer may be yet in cluster and connected.

**Split-Brain Types :**

We have three different types of split-brain, and as far as I can see yours is entry split-brain. To explain three types of split-brain :

- **Data split-brain :** Contents of the file under split-brain are different in different replica pairs and automatic healing is not possible.
- **Metadata split-brain :**, The metadata of the files (example, user defined extended attribute) are different and automatic healing is not possible.
- **Entry split-brain :** It happens when a file have different gfids on each of the replica pair.

---

#### What is GFID ?

**GlusterFS internal file identifier (GFID)** is a uuid that is unique to each file across the entire cluster. This is analogous to inode number in a normal filesystem. The GFID of a file is stored in its xattr named `trusted.gfid`. To find the path from GFID, I highly recommend you read [this official article](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Troubleshooting/gfid-to-path/) provided by GlusterFS.

---

### How to resolve entry split-brain?

There are multiple methods to prevent split-brain from occurring but to resolve it, the corresponding gfid-link files must be removed. The gfid-link files are present in the .glusterfs directory in the top-level directory of the brick. By the way, beware that before deleting the gfid-links, you must ensure that there are no hard links to the files present on that brick. If hard-links exist, you must delete them either. Then you can use self-healing process by running the following commands.

In the meantime, to view the list of files on a volume that are in a split-brain state you can use:

```
# gluster volume heal VOLNAME info split-brain
```

You should also beware that for replicated volumes, when a brick goes offline and comes back online, self-healing is required to resync all the replicas.

To check the healing status of volumes and files you can use:

```
# gluster volume heal VOLNAME info
```

Since you are using version 3.5, you don't have auto healing. So after doing the steps mentioned earlier, You need to trigger self-healing. To do so:

- Only on the files which require healing:

  `# gluster volume heal VOLNAME`
- On all the files:

  `# gluster volume heal VOLNAME full`

I hope this will help you through fixing your problem. Please read the official docs for further information. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I think [document](http://staged-gluster-docs.readthedocs.io/en/release3.7.0beta1/Features/heal-info-and-split-brain-resolution/) is clear pretty enough, it even gave you a similar example.

And for Gluesterfs's healing commands such as

```
gluster volume heal **VOLNAME** split-brain latest-mtime **FILE**
```

> FILE can be either the full file name as seen from the root of the volume **(or) the gfid-string representation of the file**

So you don't need worries about that.

And as [convert GFID to path](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Troubleshooting/gfid-to-path/) says:

> GlusterFS internal file identifier (GFID) is a uuid that is unique to each file across the entire cluster.

this [script](https://gist.github.com/semiosis/4392640) may tell you which filename belongs to which gfid, but brain split happened, it may not have a filename.

You're running 3.5 and don't have a semi-auto heal cmd, so you may need to fix confliction yourself manually which normally means decide which gfid file need to be deleted.

Comment: My version of Gluster doesn't seem to have that command, otherwise, yes, that's straightforward. Also, I don't have filenames, I have uuids.

Answer (score 2):

split-brain occurs when two nodes of a cluster are disconnected. Each node thinks the other one is not working.

[image: split brain]

To fix it, you have to understand why your two nodes are not talking to each other anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I fix it?

Split-brain resolution can be found either [here](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Troubleshooting/heal-info-and-split-brain-resolution/). In case is would not help much, the manual how-to [here](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Troubleshooting/split-brain/) should do the job. For the case, I see [the article](http://lists.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-devel/2014-May/040751.html) also helpful.

**How to avoid Split-brain.**

Protection against network partitions is done through a quorum voting algorithm. In case a host fails, or there is a split-brain scenario where the nodes continue to run but can no longer communicate to each other, the remaining node or nodes in the cluster race to place a SCSI reservation on the witness drive. In the case of a split-brain, the witness will help to decide which of the hosts who is holding a copy of the data should take over control.

**Some examples.**

VMware VSAN allows running 2-node cluster with the witness drive running on a 3rd host or in the cloud. [Source](http://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/products/vsan/vmware-virtual-san-6.2-stretched-cluster-guide.pdf)

StarWind Virtual SAN runs in just 2-node setup using Microsoft Failover Cluster service, that also contains quorum voting mechanism to avoid the split-brain issue. [Source](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/technical_papers/StarWind-High-Availability-Best-practices.pdf)

For both, Heartbeat network is used to serve/monitoring the communication between nodes and quorum. In order to avoid a split-brain, I see it’s mandatory to go with redundant Heartbeat channels.